# Let an image's size fit scrollviewer in uwp

Tags: uwp

Fisrt is the code, it will be more easier to understand.

```
<ScrollViewer ZoomMode="Enabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Image x:Name="image"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

When I set img's Source, it will show the picture's full size.....This result we can see part of the picture, if we want to see the full picture, we have to zoom out.

How to set the code, to let the picture at full extent mode(fit the the scrollviewer' size)?

Comment: in default image is show in full page and will resize automatically according to screen size, so what you want and zoom in zom out work perfectly

Comment: Okay are you want if scroll viewer size is limited or changed to image should automatically fit on it , so answer will be this : My Answer

Answer (score 1):

If Your ScrollViewer Size is limited or changed so image should be automatically fit on it SizeChangedEvent will do this for you, in example i limited the scroll viewer size, You can remove that Height and width or adjust according to your requirement.

Example

**XAML**

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollview" ZoomMode="Enabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="300" Width="150" SizeChanged="scrollview_SizeChanged">
    <Image x:Name="image" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Source="Assets/YourImage.jpg" Stretch="Uniform"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

**C#**

```
private void scrollview_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    image.Width = scrollview.ViewportWidth;
    image.Height = scrollview.ViewportHeight;
}
```

Comment: This works. But the image is left and top aligned. How to set both center aligned. HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" not work

Comment: In image set horizontal and vertical alignment = center , view updated answer

Comment: If you don't  limited the scroll viewer size, or a page just only have a scroll viewer, then it's  left and top aligned again :(

Comment: or try to set both VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"